# Is there a type that can be assigned from both a List<T> and Collection<T> in C#?

Tags: c#, collections, polymorphism

I have the following two classes in C#:

```
class DbModel{
    public List<string> Values {get; set;}
    //...other proerties...
}
```

and

```
class ViewModel{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Values {get; set;}
    //...other proerties...
}
```

I would like to create a common `Interface` that both classes implement, so I can pass either of the two in some methods. Is this even possible? I tried something like:

```
public interface IModel{
    IEnumerable<string> Values {get; set;}
}
```

but this does not work, even though both List and `ObservableCollection<string>` can be assigned to an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Is there a way around this? What would be the best workaround (if any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried this before, creating nice "domain" interfaces you apply to entities of all sorts, so you can write code that operates on the interface instead of on the domain entity, but you'll run into problems real quick.

For starters, when a class implements an interface, it has to match the interface's members types exactly. Sure, both `List<T>` and `ObservableCollection<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but that doesn't mean they both satisfy that interface member's declaration.

So you'll have to implement that particular type. You can do so for example using an explicit interface implementation. But the interface member has both a getter and a setter:

```
class DbModel : IModel
{
    public List<string> Values {get; set;}

    IEnumerable<string> IModel.Values
    {
        get { return Values; }
        set
        {
            Values = ... // now what?
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel : IModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Values {get; set;}

    IEnumerable<string> IModel.Values
    {
        get { return Values; }
        set
        {
            Values = ... // now what?
        }
    }
}
```

You probably *need* the setter, because you want some common code to be able to assign the `Values` collection. And an `IEnumerable<T>` is not really useful for anything but enumerating.

So you'll have to convert the incoming `values` to the type relevant to the class in the setter. For example `Values = values.ToList()` in the former.

And then you have a caller:

```
IModel dbModel = new DbModel();

var values = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" };

dbModel.Values = values;

values.Add("baz");
```

What will `dbModel.Values` be after this code? Hint: it won't contain `"baz"`. Don't take this approach, it will bite you.

Forget about the common interface. Identify the actual problem that interface is supposed to solve, and solve it in another way.

Comment: Thanks, that's the approach I was using at the moment (covnerting the collection inside the setter) thank you for pointing out the potential pitfall! I will probably limit the use of the interface to parts of the code that only need to read the contents of the collection without adding elements, so I can use simple explicit implementation with only the get accessor.

Comment: It gets worse when you have properties of (collections of) other domain interfaces in your interfaces (what if `IModel` has an `IModel2` property?). Then you need casting/conversion/mapping/..., after which updates to the original won't be propagated to where you assigned it. Again, confusing.

Answer (score 2):

C# does not have covariant return types (although they [have been proposed](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2844)). Therefore you'll need to use explicit interface implementations (as Lasse mentioned).

You probably don't want your `Values` property to be settable. If it is settable, then anyone can set any type which implements `IEnumerable<string>`, even though the underlying `ViewModel`/`DbModel` only supports a very specific type.

```
public interface IModel
{
    IEnumerable<string> Values { get; }
}

public class ViewModel : IModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<string> IModel.Values => Values;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although this is only useful for read-only properties (only "get" accessor)

Comment: Yes, as I pointed out it doesn't make sense to add a `set` accessor. As @CodeCaster pointed out, if you need a `set` accessor, you probably need a different design. You could get around it by putting an `AddValues` method on the interface, or returning an `ICollection<T>` rather than an `IEnumerable<T>` (which has an `Add` method)